# Question about a quotient topology collapsing a set to a point

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $E$ is a closed subset of $X$. What does it mean to 'consider the quotient obtained by collapsing $E$ to a point'? I get that we now consider all the points in $E$ to be 'the same', but what happens to the open sets (i.e. what are the open sets in the quotient space)?

Comment: It's the quotient toplogy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology) The relation is given by: $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=y$ or $x,y\in E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quotient of any topological space $X$ can be constructed by considering any [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $X$ and "modding out" by the equivalence relation this partition defines$^\dagger$.  That is to say, the elements of the quotient space $X/\!\sim$ are precisely the various subsets of the partition -- i.e. the different *equivalence classes*:
$$X/ \!\sim \ = \ \Big\{  \{y \in X \ | \ y \sim x \} \ | \ x \in X \Big\}$$

Now consider the natural surjective map $f: X \rightarrow X/ \!\sim$ that sends each point to its equivalence class. The open sets in $X/\!\sim$ are those sets $U$ whose preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

---

$^\dagger$There is a bijective correspondence between possible partitions of a set and possible equivalence relations one can define on that set.